# Table Of Content widjet in arcgis javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, table-of-contents

I'm using TOC widjet in my application using arcgis javascript api, it is working, but the problem is that the plus and minus images which collapse or expand the tree is not appearing.
[image]

I noticed that it comes from css file called carlo.css, I included the file, but the elements didn't take properties from this file, I'm not sure what's the problem, anyone can help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got where the problem is, I didn't add a class name called claro to the parent div of the all layers, I added like this:

```
    <div class="claro" >
       <div id="layersDiv>
       </div>
   </div>
```

And it works after that.